# How do I remember session of @abacritt/angularx-social-login after refresh

Tags: angular, access-token, angular-social-login

On angular using the package:
[@abacritt/angularx-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login)

I am using version `2.0.0`.

After successfully login in once using google login provider, I would like the browser to remember the login after refreshing or closing the browser.

I want to do it client side only. (unless it's not secure like that?)

I am guessing I should save the token as cookie on the browser or on local storage.
I am just not sure how to do it.

This is what I currently do:

```
import { SocialAuthService, SocialUser } from '@abacritt/angularx-social-login';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  public user: SocialUser;
  public loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private authService: SocialAuthService) {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe(async (user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.loggedIn = user != null;
    });
  }
}
```

Which is just getting the user logged into.

Comment: both are legit ways for fixing the issue, in my opinion storing them as cookies is the better approach

Comment: @AlexanderMladzhov But how do I do that though?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a newbie answer but this is how I did it

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
      this.loggedIn = user != null;
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', user.idToken);
    }); 
   }
```